# Micronaut socket is not importing

Tags: micronaut

```
import io.micronaut.websocket.WebSocketBroadcaster;
import io.micronaut.websocket.WebSocketSession;
import io.micronaut.websocket.annotation.*;
import java.util.function.Predicate;
```

I have added the imports to micronaut 1.0.0.M4. but it is not present.

how can i fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

The web socket support was introduce with 1.0.0.RC1 and wasn't in M4.

We released 1.0.0.RC2 today so you probably want to skip RC1 at this point.

Comment: Thanks will try the rc2

Comment: The web socket support also works in RC3... and will work in the 1.0 release, and likely all subsequent releases.  You were using a version of the software that predates the existence of the classes you were trying to reference.